# How to use luminati proxy manager to get a 20 IPs with long constant session on each which can be accessed by using different ports?

Tags: proxy, screen-scraping

Trying to use "Multiply port per ip" from pool on the general tab of settings, but requests go only through 1 IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure you have a pool of at least 20 IPs in your zone.

When you select 'Multiply port per IP' there should be a pop up allowing you to select which IPs you want to assign.

Go back to the 'general' screen, you should see the port is now 24000:1..20. Click the tiny dropdown button next to the port to reveal ports 24000 through 24020, each will have it's own unique IP.